# Overlaying text boxes

Tags: text

I'm working on a writing project that requires some unusual typesetting.

One of the things I want to achieve is to write two lines of text in the place of one, deliberately overlaying them. Basically, like creating two text layers in Photoshop or InDesign and putting one over the other.

Yes, this will look a mess, but I have my reasons for wanting to experiment with it.[image]

Can I achieve this in LaTeX?

Comment: There are many possible approaches.  Are there any constraints to which you need to conform? Example, both sentences share one word that serves as the overlap anchor?

Comment: ...for example, overlaying similar words may require some specific overlapping: `First sentence of the text\llap{More text}\rlap{.} over it.`

Answer (score 2):

[image: negative hspace]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    FIRST SENTENCE \hspace*{-2cm} \textbf{MORE TEXT OVER IT}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know where you want the overlap to start in terms of the words, `\rlap` could be useful:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614535/86}
\begin{document}
    FIRST \rlap{SENTENCE}{\tiny MORE TEXT OVER IT}
\end{document}
```

(the `\tiny` is just to show the different texts a bit more clearly)

[image: Overlapping text]